# Firefox delay switching from scrolling body to scrolling div

Tags: html, css, firefox, scroll, css-position

I'm building a site where the horizontal site submenu "sticks" just under the header as the user scrolls down. The site layout is like this:

[header]

[advert]

[submenu]

[content]

I'm using jquery to determine the submenu+content div position and then adding a class with position: fixed to lock it when it has moved up to cover the ad, and at that point the inner content div containing the site content continues to be scrollable. In Safari and Firefox this is a smooth transition; the user scrolls, the submenu locks, the scrolling continues seamlessly even though it's an inner div that's being scrolled.
In Firefox however, there's a 2-3 second pause when the submenu locks before the content div becomes scrollable again.
Can anyone suggest why, and how to overcome this?

Cheers

Comment: how about having us let a look at some code?

Comment: An [example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would really help.

Comment: Hey guys sorry about the delay. Stripped everything down to it's bare essentials. It works fine except: The body area is cut off at the bottom and putting bottom margins etc on DIVs isnt helping, and in Firefox, once the page stops scrolling and the #center-column-content starts scrolling, there's a delay of a couple of seconds where Firefox wont scroll. [Here's the Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pr0fess0r/hu0nvk5q/)